# How do I determine the expected duration/runtime of older Adventurer's League adventures for purposes of DM rewards?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, experience-points, dnd-adventurers-league

In reference to this question: [How do I apply & record DM Experience Rewards?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113911/how-do-i-apply-record-dm-experience-rewards)

Where in a published D&DAL Module (I'm specifically working with the Tyranny of Dragons modules) would I find the part where it says the expected duration/runtime? All it says is the XP and Downtime rewards for the adventure, but the DM's guide for AL says that their new rules trump the old guidelines, and that I gain XP & GP based on the amount of time the adventure is meant to run, as well as the level of the party.

Alternatively, if it is not written in said modules, how would one go about calculating or otherwise determining what time duration to use when calculating these DM rewards?

Comment: It is, apologies.

Comment: None needed! The nice thing about duplicates is it creates new wordings that people can successfully search for.

Answer (score 0):

The content catalog, included in the Dungeon Master pack on Dmsguild, provides the prescribed runtime of all adventures (modules) of all seasons.

The downtime a DM receoves is the same that his players receive.